# Delete every Nth line in shell

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I'm trying to delete a line after N lines using awk and I can't seem to get it right.
The file format is like this

```
YYYYYY
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
YYYYYY
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
```

The real example would be

```
office3
3
1
office3
6
1
office3
6
3
office3
1
1
```

How can I delete the YY lines or the lines that say "office". I need to delete a line every two lines regardless of their content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894986/how-can-i-delete-every-xth-line-in-a-text-file || delete: http://superuser.com/questions/396536/how-to-keep-only-every-nth-line-of-a-file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have GNU sed, you could use the `n~m` (`n` skip `m`) address notation

`sed '1~3d' file`

which deletes every third line, starting at the first.

Comment: This solved it for me. I didn't know abot that sed function. Thank you!

Comment: When using this sed 'n~md', is there a limit of how big n and m can be? I tested '33~66d' with the attempt to delete 33 lines for every 66 lines, but it does not work

Comment: @jasper afaik `33~66d` would mean delete every 66th line counting from line 33 (i.e. the 33rd, 99th, 165th, ...)

Comment: then how should this command be written to delete 33 lines for every 66 lines?

Answer (score 13):

To select only lines modulo `N` with `awk` try

```
awk '!(NR%2)' file
```

or

```
awk 'NR%3==0' file
```

Here `NR` denotes number of rows processed so far.

---

In your specific case (remove all lines with `Y`):

```
$ echo 'YYYYYY
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
YYYYYY
XXXXXX
XXXXXX' | awk '!(NR%3==1)'
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
XXXXXX
```

Comment: in  this example, we want to delete lines 1 and 4, so `NR%3==1`

Comment: This solution has the advantage of being standard and portable to all POSIX systems (even pre-POSIX ones as except for the first one, it works in the original `awk` from 1979)