# Delete three lines in specific step

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have data like that (this is only a small part):

```
  454SOL     OW20704   0.317   0.251   5.525
  454SOL    HW120705   0.388   0.322   5.531
  454SOL    HW220706   0.229   0.290   5.553
  462SOL     OW20728   0.130   1.821   5.295
  462SOL    HW120729   0.120   1.806   5.394
  462SOL    HW220730   0.044   1.857   5.259
  469SOL     OW20749   0.461   1.266   5.451
  469SOL    HW120750   0.411   1.267   5.365
  469SOL    HW220751   0.398   1.248   5.527
  500SOL     OW20842   1.754   1.223   5.312
  500SOL    HW120843   1.845   1.184   5.299
  500SOL    HW220844   1.762   1.319   5.336
  502SOL     OW20848   1.592   1.629   5.349
  502SOL    HW120849   1.619   1.663   5.259
  502SOL    HW220850   1.671   1.591   5.395
  515SOL     OW20887   1.587   0.779   5.394
  515SOL    HW120888   1.495   0.817   5.389
  515SOL    HW220889   1.647   0.826   5.329
  516SOL     OW20890   1.013   0.105   5.494
  516SOL    HW120891   1.019   0.190   5.442
  516SOL    HW220892   1.045   0.029   5.437
  522SOL     OW20908   1.728   0.935   5.578
  522SOL    HW120909   1.682   0.928   5.489
  522SOL    HW220910   1.666   0.979   5.644
```

I want to delete three lines, the next 9 lines leave alone, and then again delete 3 lines. In this case, I want to delete lines 10,11,12 and 22,23,24.
Expected output

```
  454SOL     OW20704   0.317   0.251   5.525
  454SOL    HW120705   0.388   0.322   5.531
  454SOL    HW220706   0.229   0.290   5.553
  462SOL     OW20728   0.130   1.821   5.295
  462SOL    HW120729   0.120   1.806   5.394
  462SOL    HW220730   0.044   1.857   5.259
  469SOL     OW20749   0.461   1.266   5.451
  469SOL    HW120750   0.411   1.267   5.365
  469SOL    HW220751   0.398   1.248   5.527
  502SOL     OW20848   1.592   1.629   5.349
  502SOL    HW120849   1.619   1.663   5.259
  502SOL    HW220850   1.671   1.591   5.395
  515SOL     OW20887   1.587   0.779   5.394
  515SOL    HW120888   1.495   0.817   5.389
  515SOL    HW220889   1.647   0.826   5.329
  516SOL     OW20890   1.013   0.105   5.494
  516SOL    HW120891   1.019   0.190   5.442
  516SOL    HW220892   1.045   0.029   5.437
```

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
awk 'NR%10==0 || NR%11==0 || NR%12==0' sol.txt | tee sol_after.txt
```

and it doesn't work.

I need to dele lines on the whole file, so delete 10-12, then 22-24, then 34-36, 46-48, etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete every Nth line in shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168004/delete-every-nth-line-in-shell)

Comment: @MarcusMüller not really I tried this #!/bin/bash
awk 'NR%10==0 || NR%11==0 || NR%12==0' sol.txt | tee sol_after.txt and it doesn't work

Comment: the way you pasted it into your question, the whole line is commented out. Is this *really* what you did, Jakub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ seq 30 | awk 'NR%12 !~ /^(10|11|0)$/'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ seq 30 | awk 'NR%12 == 10{c=3} !(c&&c--)'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for what `c&&c--` does and more information.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU sed, with its "skip" operator:

```
$ printf 'Line %2d\n' {1..25} | sed  -n '10~12{n;n;n};p'
Line  1
Line  2
Line  3
Line  4
Line  5
Line  6
Line  7
Line  8
Line  9
Line 13
Line 14
Line 15
Line 16
Line 17
Line 18
Line 19
Line 20
Line 21
Line 25
```

Answer (score 1):

With each `awk` :

```c
awk -v n=9 -v d=3 '
    ((NR - skip) > n && (NR - skip) <= n+d){f = 1;next}
    NR > n && f {f=0;skip = NR-1} 1
' file
```

Tested with more lines :

```bsh
for i in {1..50}
do printf '%d\n' "$i"
done | awk -v n=9 -v d=3 '
    ((NR - skip) > n && (NR - skip) <= n+d){f = 1;next}
    NR > n && f {f=0;skip = NR-1} 1
'
```

---

you can wrap it in a `sh` script and choose which lines to omit by simply changing the bounds:
`n` the number of lines to print and
`d` the number of lines to omit once the `n` limit is reached